# how we can open my app at daily alarm.can i use pushregistry as a daily alarm

Tags: java, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40

I am working on nokia sdk2.0  using lwuit1.5.i have used pushregistry in my app.it is working properly.An alarm open on specific time as i set and aap open on view click.Now i want to use the pushregistry as dailiy alarm .so please suggest me is it possible and there is another way to use daily alarm and my app open .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you only have the option to use `PushRegistry` you should keep in mind that you will have to set the time again in a manual way. This happens because `PushRegistry` need to set the long date everytime that you want it to set it.

When you put a new long date in the `PushRegistry` it override the last date that you have put in it.

In my opinion it will be very hard to set a daily alarm using `PushRegistry`. I have to do it in one of my apps and finally I set all the alarms using `Event` in the calendar of the device. Take a look on it, I think that it will fit your needs better.

Comment: can we complete this process in background ? and when we register the pushregistry it open a permission so how it will happen .how we can register the push registry in background

Comment: Yes, but you will need a running thread to do this...and this thread will be thrown from your MIDlet. If the user doesn't open your app the PushRegistry will not be launched...you know?